# Get list of values in type

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, is it possible to dynamically get a list of values in a type? A specific example is generating a complete deck of playing cards by combining one of each rank and suit to create a list of cards:

```
data Rank = 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | J | Q | K | A
data Suit = Spades | Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs
data Card = Card Rank Suit

deck :: [Card]
deck = -- get list of ranks and suits to create a deck --
```

How would this be accomplished without hard-coding values?

Comment: Yes, but this has nothing to do with “list of types”.

Comment: ... or with type classes. (`J`, `Q`, `Spades`, `Hearts`, etc. are not types.)

Comment: What would be the correct terminology?

Comment: @Shane `Spades` is a value (of type `Suit`). It is also a constructor. (For a different example, `Just "foo"` is a value (of type `Maybe String`), and `Just` is a constructor.)

Comment: @duplode So would a better question be "Get list of values in type?"

Comment: @Shane Yes, it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way is getting the compiler to generate the code through a derived `Enum` instance.

```
data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seve | Eight | Nine | Ten | J | Q | K | A
    deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

data Suit = Spades | Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs
    deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

data Card = Card Rank Suit

deck :: [Card]
deck = do
    rank <- enumFrom minBound :: [Rank]
    suit <- enumFrom minBound :: [Suit]
    return $ Card rank suit
```

or the list comprehension version:

```
deck :: [Card]
deck = [Card rank suit | rank <- enumFrom minBound :: [Rank], suit <- enumFrom minBound :: [Suit]]
```

Comment: `11:13: Couldn't match expected type ‘[Rank]’ with actual type ‘Int’`

Comment: @Shane yeah sorry. it should be `enumFrom`, not `fromEnum`

Comment: you can use a list comprehension as well.  I'll add that alternative

Comment: The `[Rank]` and `[Suit]` annotations aren't essential (the use of `Card` drives inference appropriately).

Comment: Also, I added a brief explanatory sentence. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.